# How to make an audio player with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I am trying to make an audio player that display's the song title, artist name and song cover.
I have 32 songs to add to that music player, so I am also trying to add a next / previous button and make the play button switch to pause button when a song is playing.

I am new to javascript so I have no idea how to do that without using Jquery or a library.
thank you for your help.

here is a link to my code.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd18a 0%, #fbc2eb88 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

.player {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.75em;
}

.player>div {
  align-self: center;
}

.songCover {
  justify-self: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.songCover>img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.about {
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.songTitle {
  width: 125px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #c80028;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.Artist {
  width: 125px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  color: #c80028;
  align-self: end;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.playerButtons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  max-width: 275px;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

button {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
  all: unset;
}

.play,
.prevSong,
.nextSong,
.pause {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pause {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header class="top">
  <div class="player">
    <div class="songCover">
      <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56454c01e4b0177ad4141742/56f3eeaa6e06f2df013dd6cd/56f3ef166e06f2df013de90e/1458827030471/Im-Gonna-Be-500-Miles-Cover.jpg?format=original" alt="song Cover" />
    </div>
    <div class="about">
      <div class="songTitle">Song Name</div>
      <div class="Artist">Artist name here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="playerButtons">
      <button class="prevSong">
              <img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_68793.png" alt="previous" height="15px" />
            </button>
      <button class="play">
              <img src="http://www.lynnettechadwick.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/play-button.png" alt="play" height="20px" />
            </button>
      <button class="pause">
              <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180412/qle/kisspng-computer-icons-linkedin-desktop-wallpaper-pause-button-5acf7aca975286.4627736315235468266198.jpg" alt="pause" height="20px" />
            </button>
      <button class="nextSong">
              <img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_60041.png" alt="next" height="15px" />
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpho584r/18/

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: You have a whole design task here to decide on your approach. This site is for specific issues, not general questions, so you need to work on your initial stages first.

Comment: @RegEdit can you recommend resources I can check out, had no luck on codeopen, YouTube and here.